# XenServer 6.2 fails to boot on IBM System x3550 M2

Tags: xenserver, syslinux, ibm

I'm trying to install XenServer 6.2 on a IBM System x3550 M2 but it simply doesn't work.

The installation process works fine in the internal Seagate hard disk, but the machine fails to boot XenServer on the IBM hardware. The syslinux loader don't even appears, the hardware complains about failing to boot from Hard Disk 0.

I've tried using another System x3550 M2 machine to install XenServer and the results are the same. Tried other hard disk drives too with no success.

If we get the hard disk and put on a ordinary PC, XenServer *boots* fine.

I don't know what is really happening with XenServer, since we can install an ordinary Linux distribution on the same machines with success.

Looking forward for any help.

Thanks,

Comment: If using a SATA interface, you may want to check the BIOS for alternate SATA modes, like AHCI, RAID, IDE. Emulate the setting from the "ordinary" PC if possible.

Comment: I will try this Tim. I think there's some problem with UEFI too.

Comment: @Tim the problem wasn't it. It was the Legacy Only mode. The SATA adapter is in "Native mode" and not compatibility and we are able to boot XenServer 6.2 in this way... But your idea helped to figure out the problem.

Comment: Great! Did seem like a BIOS issue, glad it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved enabling Legacy Only mode in the Boot Configuration of the BIOS.

It must follow this order:
Legacy Only
Hard Disk 0

If we put only "Legacy Only", the machine fails to boot anyway.